# Commands for the maps

Tags: commutative-diagrams

[image]

I am looking for the easiest latex commands for the above mathematical maps.

Comment: Take a look at tikzcd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}
  G\arrow[d]\arrow[rd]\\
  G'\arrow[r,dashed]& H
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to create your [commutative-diagram](/questions/tagged/commutative-diagram) using also [xy](/questions/tagged/xy) package that it use a strange syntax but very similar to [tikz-cd](/questions/tagged/tikz-cd).

The command `\ar` it is an abbreviation of `\arrow` and
`@{-->}` is equivalent to *dashed*. You can try also the output with `@{.>}` (dotted arrow).
`@R=1.75pc@C=2.75pc` **(R=row distance, and C=column distance)**.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[all,cmtip]{xy}
\begin{document}
\xymatrix@R=1.75pc@C=2.75pc{
G \ar[d]\ar[dr] & \\
G'\ar@{-->}[r] & H }
\end{document}
```

Here there is the output:

[image]